# SuperHiggs Mechanism on different Backgrounds & Compactifications

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, research-level

I've been studying Bagger & Giannakis paper on the SuperHiggs Mechanism found [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0502107v1).

The paper shows how SUSY is broken by a $B_{\mu\nu}$ gauge field background restricted to $T^3$ in $M^7\times T^3$ Compactification of the heterotic string.

*My question is, have these results been generalised to different Backgrounds and/or Compactifications (Perhaps even Calabi Yau 3-folds)?*

So far my search has shown up no results, any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Please don't link to the PDF (or at least not exclusively): the abstract would be much more helpful.  Thanks.  In this case, the abstract to the paper is http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0502107v1

Comment: While we are at the topic, please link to arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0502107 _without_ version number (v1). That way we automatically get the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

After more search I have come to the (perhaps premature) conclusion that these results have not yet been generalised.

[Ioannis Giannakis](http://de.arxiv.org/find/hep-th/1/Ioannis+Giannakis/0/1/0/all/3/0) seems to be one of the leading researchers on this subject. His publication list however does not indicate any further research into the SuperHiggs mechanism.

Related Articles are:

- [arXiv:0709.2162v3](http://de.arxiv.org/abs/0709.2162v3)
- [arXiv:hep-th/0211116](http://de.arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0211116)

(I will keep this Question open for now, in case I missed something/Someone else finds something)

Comment: It seems a very interesting question. I was hoping someone would be able to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: As I'm currently searching for a nice area to do research in, I was more or less hoping this sort of outcome :)